# Using Grix, gridy to remove JTextField

Tags: java, eclipse, swing

I want to know if its possible to remove a JTextField using 
GridBagLayout and removing like this.

`PANEL.remove(gridx.5, gridy.5)` ---< is this possible?

Or how can I remove with this sort of logic.

Comment: 1) See [What is the XY problem?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377) 2) Use a [`CardLayout`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/CardLayout.html) as shown in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5786005/418556). 3) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Answer (score 1):

No there is no method that does that, you will need to write your own.

1. The `Container` class has a method `getLayout()`. This will allow you to get the `GridBagLayout` instance for your panel.
2. The `Container` class also has a method `getComponents()`

So once you get all the components in an array you iterate through the array. For each component you would:

1. Use the `getConstraints()` method of the `GridBagLayout`.
2. Then check the  `gridx` and `gridy` value of the `GridBagConstraints` object to see what clumn/row the component is in.
3. Remove the component from the panel if it meets your criteria.

After the loop is finished you invoke `revalidate()` on the panel.

Edit:

Somewhere in your code you need to set the layout manager to the GridBagLayout. Then you add components to the panel using your GridBagConstraints.

Then in the future when you want to remove the component from the panel you need to reference:

1. the JPanel you added the components to
2. the GridBagLayout of the above panel

I gave you the methods you need to accomplish this. So did you read the API for the methods I suggest you need to use?

The basic code would be:

```
GridBagLayout layout = (GridBagLayout)panel;
Component[] components = panel.getComponent();

for (each component in the array)
{
    GridBagConstraint gbc = layout.getConstraints( component )

    if (gbc.gridX == ?? && gbc.gridY = ??)
    {
        // remove the component from the panel
    }
}

panel.revalidate();
```

So I would suggest you create a method that passes in the row and column of the component you want to find. Then you can change the if condition to access these parameters.

Comment: createInPanel.getLayout();
                                List<Component> components = new ArrayList<>();
                                components.addAll(createInPanel.getComponents());

Comment: where the createInPanel is the panel which as the gridbaglayout. I don't think I understand this properly.